# Updating TextBlock at start of code block in MainWindow asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, asynchronous

I have a problem that's been bugging me for days, I've tried every option and I'm now resulting in posting my own question to find some specific help from you guys.

I need to update a TextBlock at the start of code block, which is run on a simple button click.

Here's my code:

```
private void NewProject(bool blnCopy = false, string strFileName = null)
    {
      if (App.ApplicationBusy == false)
      {
        App.ApplicationBusy = true;

        try
        {
          Action action = delegate()
          {
            Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
            lblStatus.Text = "Opening Project...";
          };

          Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, action);

          if (blnCopy == false) { Project = new GSProject((App.RecentProjectCount + 1)); }

          if (Project != null)
          {
            Projects.Add(Project);

            if (blnCopy == false)
            {
              if (strFileName == null)
              {
                Project.ProjectName = string.Format("GSProject{0}", Projects.Count.ToString());
                Project.ProjectDescription = string.Format("{0} - HW GS Project", Project.ProjectName);
                Project.LoadResource();
              }
              else
              {
                Project.Load(strFileName);
              }
            }
            else
            {
              Project = Project.Copy();
            }

            p_objNewPane = objDocker.AddDocument(Project.ProjectDisplayName, Project);

            if (p_objNewPane != null)
            {
              p_objNewPane.DataContext = Project;
              BindingOperations.SetBinding(p_objNewPane, ContentPane.HeaderProperty, new Binding("ProjectDisplayName") { Source = Project });
              p_objNewPane.Closing += new EventHandler<PaneClosingEventArgs>(ContentPane_Closing);
            }

            if (Project.CalculationExists == true)
            {
              InitializeCalculation(true);
            }
          }
          tabStartPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          objDocumentTabs.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          ModernDialog.ShowMessage(string.Format("An error has occurred:{0}{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, Application.Current.MainWindow);
        }
        finally
        {
          App.ApplicationBusy = false;
          Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
          AppStatus = "Ready";
          p_objNewPane = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

At the start of the try block, I need to update the TextBlock (lblStatus) to say what's going on. The void itself, NewProject, is on the MainWindow, and is called by a button click.

Can someone please give me an idea of where I'm going wrong? I've tried countless potential solutions, so please don't be offended if I get back to you saying I've tried it.

Regards, Tom.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, just said that you want to update a TextBox..?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is the TextBlock is not updating at all. It's just saying "Ready" (that is set on load of the MainWindow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few painful days I managed to get this working. I was barking up the wrong tree completely by looking into Task Scheduling, etc. Instead all that was needed was a DependencyProperty.

XAML (Main Window):

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblStatus"
           Text="{Binding AppStatus, IsAsync=True}"
           Grid.Column="0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
           FontSize="12"
           Foreground="White"
           Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
```

C# (Main Window):

```
public string AppStatus
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(AppStatusProperty); }
      set { SetValue(AppStatusProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppStatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AppStatus", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public void StatusBarUpdate(string strMainMessage)
    {
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { AppStatus = strMainMessage; }));
    }
```

I can then call the `StatusBarUpdate` method at any time and it will asynchronously update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WPF, Therefore implement

```
INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and use proper data binding.

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
public string StatusText
{
    get {return this.m_statusText;}

    set
    {
        if (value != this.m_statusText)
        {
            this.m_statusText= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StatusText");
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StatusText}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel - this was my original set up, and failing this I changed it to a simple lblStatus.Text to see if that made any difference.

Originally I had a INPC string called AppStatus, which the TextBlock was bound to like you have put above, then I simply called AppStatus = "Opening Project";. The outcome was the same as it is now unfortunately.

Comment: Ok but Data binding is the proper way how to do this. I would try to get this approach working.

Did you set the DataContext?
You can enable WPF bind error messages in VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks I'll let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what exactly is the problem, but looking at the code I can guess that the textbox shows "Opening Project..." only after completion of your code or shows "Ready" if `AppStatus` is doing the same thing.

If yes, the problem is that you are doing everything on the UI thread. Although you changed the text of the textbox, it will be rendered after your work is done, hence the problem. To fix this, you need to run the code from `if (blnCopy == false)` to `objDocumentTabs.SelectedIndex = 0;` on a worker thread. That will fix your problem.

You can use TPL for that and can also you `.ContinueWith` with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` and `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` to execute the finally block.

EDIT:
As you are not using MVVM, you will need a lot of `Invoke` to make your code work. As I can see p_objNewPane is also an UI element just like `Project` is a view property, it will be difficult to translate all that to TPL. You can leave code from `p_objNewPane = ...` as it is (i.e. outside worker thread). That doesn't seem to be very cpu intensive except maybe `InitializeCalculation` which you can run in another worker thread.

A better approach is that you use await/async methods to wait for all heavy lifting methods.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh - and yes you were correct, the TextBlock is not updating until the end. My problem is also that "Project" is a Dependency Property, so using say a BackgroundWorker for example, or an await Task.Run() results in an exception because I cannot access the propdp outside the UI thread.

Comment: Instead of directly assigning or modifying the dependency property, just make a new `Project` instance and return this instance as the task result. In the `ContinueWith` method, just assign your dependency property to the returned `Project` instance.